# What object let's me have two different components on the screen at once?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a minesweeper game and I sort of want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an2oP.jpg).

To clarify, I want there to be a top object so I can place the timer, the number of mines left, and the smiley face button on it (I do not want to put these on the action menu).

And the bottom object be the actual game (I already made this as a Table Layout).

The problem is, I don't know what kind of object I should be using for this. Fragments? Activities? Layouts? What do I need to accomplish this?

Comment: "What do I need to accomplish this?" I think what you need first is to do one or two tutorials on how to make Android apps.

Comment: I have, I've even went over it again. No mentioning of this in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to put these on the action menu

Then you need to decide between Activity & Fragment. Layout is common for both Activity & Fragment which need for views.

If you use fragment then it may be little hard to implement because you constantly communicate between your table fragment & timer fragment. But advantage you found that you use it more flexible way for different device size.

I think it is easy to implement in activity. Just need vertical Linear Layout to separate your table & timer.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while, for each fragment's onCreateView I got the layout associated with the view and manipulated the layout's position.